# Cross-difference between arrays without using for loop

Tags: r

Using the following code:

```
a <- seq(1, 10, 1)
b <- seq(2, 20, 2)
```

I would like to subtract `a[i - 1]` from `b[i]` for each `i`, in order to obtain something like

```
c <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(b)) {
   c[i] <- b[i] - a[i - 1]
}
```

but I would like to do this **without** using `for()` loop.

Anyone knows how to do it in **just one** command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `a` and `b` are the same length, I've assumed you'd like to first trim the last element off of `b`. (Try `b - a[-1]` to see why that's probably desirable.)

```
b[-length(b)] - a[-1]
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thank you; then I guess there's no wrapper function to deal with cross-differences without having first trimmed elements off of arrays to align them.

Comment: @user1638221 -- Not a named base one, but you can always do something like this: `f <- function(x,y) y[-length(y)] - x[-1]; f(1:10, 20:11)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with time series:

```
 a <- ts(seq(1, 10, 1))
 b <- ts(seq(2, 20, 2))
 b- lag(a,1) 
##-----
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 9 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Not that I am necessarily recommending this. The base time-series formalism is a widely feared source of confusion. Most people avoid it, giving preference to the zoo and xts classed objects.